# different settings after f5 in ionic proyect

Tags: angular, ionic4

When I'm testing my proyect, the first time after ionic serve, the proyect loads in my browser with a style and after I reload the page, or do some changes to the code, the style changes and the logic of the proyect seems to change aswell (call to methods that generated error before now doesn't generate any error)

Example before i reload the project (ionic serve):
[the tabs bar doesn't fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ec6.png)

After i reload or make some change in the code:
[tabs bar fits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb1dS.png)

I don't have any error at the moment of doing ionic serve, i created a new proyect and copy the code but the error persisted

PD: When i deploy the apk in an android device, it loads with the first settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just formated my pc and installed again everything from scratch and now loads consistenly one setting